# android function in class throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, class, methods, nullpointerexception, return

I've made a class which holds some string and integers, in that class I made a function to convert the data in the class in to a readable string;

```
    public String GetConditions() {
        String BigString = null;
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");  
        try {
            BigString += "Depth: " + ci(Depth) + eol;

and so on...
```

Because I have to convert many integers, I made an extra function to convert a integer to a string;

```
public String ci(Integer i) { 
    // convert integer to string
    if (i != null) {
        String a = new Integer(i).toString();
    return  a;
    } else {
    return "n/a";
    }
}
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` exception on `return a`. I'm quite new to Java, this is probally a noob question... Sorry about, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I found the problem, I've tried to add something to a string which was 'null' , this line:

```
String BigString = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to convert an `Integer` to a `String`: use [`String#valueOf(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29).

```
public String ci(Integer i)
{
    return i == null ? "n/a" : String.valueOf(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `Integer` you pass in your method to string, instead of instantiating a new one.

You can do it straight forward like:

`String a = i.toString();`

or

`String a = Integer.toString(i.intValue());`

Comment: Casting an `Integer` to a `String` will not even compile.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I found the problem, I've tried to add something to a string which was 'null' , this line: 
    String BigString = null;

Comment: @Lectere, really? In plain Java I got this: http://ideone.com/2JaH8 - so it must be that Android works differently in that regard?